# Pop OS linux distro very slow in booting

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04, pop-os

I have installed Pop OS onto my machine completely replacing Windows 10. I am loving it so far. The only frustration I have about it is the boot time. While booting it stays on a black screen for a minute and twenty seconds. I never used a Linux computer, so troubleshooting the slow boot issue has become a nightmare for me. Anybody who has had years of experience on Linux please help get rid of this issue.

I am attaching here all the info I got about my machine, the processes running etc.

```
**inxi -Fxz**

System:    Kernel: 5.8.0-7642-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.0 Desktop: N/A Distro: Pop!_OS 20.10 
           base: Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy 
Machine:   Type: Desktop System: DELL product: Studio XPS 435T/9000 v: 00 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: DELL model: 0X501H v: A02 serial: <filter> BIOS: DELL v: A16 date: 07/28/2009 
Battery:   Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 2S charge: 55% (should be ignored) 
           status: Discharging 
           Device-2: hidpp_battery_1 model: Logitech K780 Multi-Device Wireless Keyboard charge: 100% (should be ignored) 
           status: Discharging 
CPU:       Info: 6-Core model: Intel Xeon W3690 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Nehalem rev: 2 L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 82992 
           Speed: 1767 MHz min/max: N/A Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1767 2: 2549 3: 3457 4: 2454 5: 2428 6: 3458 7: 2382 8: 2561 
           9: 3457 10: 2744 11: 2332 12: 3458 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] vendor: eVga.com. driver: nvidia v: 460.39 bus ID: 09:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 5120x1440~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.39 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 82801JI HD Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP106 High Definition Audio vendor: eVga.com. driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 09:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-7642-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 0400 bus ID: 02:00.0 
           IF: wlp2s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Dell driver: r8169 v: kernel port: c800 
           bus ID: 05:00.0 
           IF: enp5s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 32.39 GiB (6.8%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 950 PRO 512GB size: 476.94 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 464.51 GiB used: 32.39 GiB (7.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 4.00 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) dev: /dev/dm-0 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 36 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 0% 
Info:      Processes: 360 Uptime: N/A Memory: 15.62 GiB used: 1.17 GiB (7.5%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 10.2.0 
           Packages: 1850 Shell: Bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.1.07
```

systemd-analyze

```
Startup finished in 5.701s (kernel) + 8.200s (userspace) = 13.902s 
graphical.target reached after 8.188s in userspace



 **systemd-analyze blame**

6.780s NetworkManager-wait-online.service  
3.636s plymouth-quit-wait.service          
 897ms snapd.service                       
 719ms fwupd.service                       
 650ms systemd-logind.service              
 591ms accounts-daemon.service             
 472ms man-db.service                      
 450ms dev-nvme0n1p1.device                
 428ms system76-power.service              
 379ms gpu-manager.service                 
 316ms udisks2.service                     
 313ms dev-mapper-cryptswap.swap           
 299ms logrotate.service                   
 246ms systemd-resolved.service            
 244ms upower.service                      
 228ms dev-loop0.device                    
 226ms systemd-timesyncd.service           
 159ms networkd-dispatcher.service         
 157ms dev-loop1.device                    
 146ms systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap.service
 133ms user@1000.service                   
 133ms dev-loop2.device                    
 126ms apparmor.service                    
 123ms systemd-modules-load.service        
 118ms snap-core18-1988.mount              
 117ms systemd-journald.service            
 115ms snap-snapd-11036.mount              
 110ms networking.service                  
 108ms grub-initrd-fallback.service        
 106ms snap-flutter-50.mount               
 101ms systemd-journal-flush.service       
  95ms lvm2-monitor.service                
  92ms avahi-daemon.service                
  92ms NetworkManager.service              
  92ms polkit.service                      
  90ms bluetooth.service                   
  83ms systemd-rfkill.service              
  83ms systemd-udev-trigger.service        
  70ms switcheroo-control.service          
  66ms apport.service                      
  63ms wpa_supplicant.service              
  61ms keyboard-setup.service              
  60ms grub-common.service                 
  59ms thermald.service                    
  50ms systemd-udevd.service               
  49ms gdm.service                         
  43ms e2scrub_reap.service                
  42ms geoclue.service                     
  40ms ModemManager.service                
  40ms lm-sensors.service                  
  36ms snapd.apparmor.service              
  34ms rsyslog.service                     
  32ms snap-snapd-11107.mount              
  28ms packagekit.service                  
  25ms pppd-dns.service                    
  22ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service      
  20ms plymouth-read-write.service         
  20ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service    
  18ms snapd.seeded.service                
  18ms plymouth-start.service              
  16ms dev-hugepages.mount                 
  16ms dev-mqueue.mount                    
  15ms modprobe@drm.service                
  15ms sys-kernel-debug.mount              
  15ms systemd-sysctl.service              
  14ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
```

Comment: There is nobody who had any experience like mine?

Comment: just so you know, i have same slow boot (ryzen 5700g and nvme ssd) only with pop os, speed boot with other